# Tabs with :target pseudo adding active style w/o Javascript

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have simple navigation, where did it with :target pseudo. I have however some style for currently selected tab like .active. I also have styles for :target which about the same. The problem is that Actively selected tab uses some ::before pseudo to add down arrow. This is something I can't achieve in combination with :target. Is it possible? 
I want to have ::before content on :target:

```
        <nav>
            <div class="nav nav-wrapper">
                <ul role="navigation">
                    <li><a href="#top" class="active">Top 50</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#mid">Mid</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bottom">Bottom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

and have

```
.nav ul li a:hover, 
.nav ul li a.active, 
.nav ul li a:target {
    background-color: white;
    color: #585858;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul li a::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    ...
}


.nav ul li a.active::before {// will obviously not work, but it is something I can achieve}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it works doing `.active::before`, and you can do `:target::before`, showed in below sample

```css
.nav ul li a:hover,
.nav ul li a.active,
.nav ul li a:target {
  background-color: white;
  color: #585858;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul li a::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
.nav ul li a:target::after {
  content: " ...Hey there, 123";
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-wrapper">
    <ul role="navigation">
      <li><a href="#top" class="active">Top 50</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#mid">Mid</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#bottom" id="bottom">Bottom - click me to show :target::before</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

Updated with a sample based on a comment, how target 2 items using `:target` pseudo class

```css
.nav ul li a:hover,
.nav ul li a.active,
.nav ul li a:target {
  background-color: white;
  color: #585858;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul li a::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
div:target ~ nav #bottom1::after,
div:target ~ #bottom2::after {
  content: " ...Hey there, 123";
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom"></div>

<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-wrapper">
    <ul role="navigation">
      <li><a href="#top" class="active">Top 50</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#mid">Mid</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#bottom" id="bottom1">Bottom - click me to show :target::before</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<section id="bottom2"></section>
```

Comment: I want to do :target::before and avoid .active as it required some javascript involved. :target::before doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: @Vladyn It works, but you need to give the element to target an id

Comment: That way, adding target::before I'm adding pseudo to the nav element and I'll lose reference to the section with id="bottom". This is to break the nav functionality. I wanted when section is targeted ./.../#bottom not only the to be visible, but to have a reference to the tab that shows that section and apply to it pseudo ::before.

Comment: @Vladyn I updated my answer with a second sample, showing how one can target 2 items with the :target pseudo class ... if you meant something else in your comment, and as no such info about a section is present in the question,  please accept this and post a 2:nd one

Comment: Thant's it! Thank you!